# Radius of convergence of power series solution for $y'' + ln(x+1)y' + y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

This is a homework problem, but it's not worth anything assessment-wise.

> Both power series solutions of $y'' + ln(x + 1)y' + y = 0$ centered at the ordinary point x = 0 are guaranteed to converge for all x in which one of the following intervals? a) $(-1, \infty)$, b) $(-\infty, \infty)$, c) $[-1/2,1/2]$, d) $[-1,1]$

I have to say, I feel under prepared for this question. I had a go at just doing the usual power series substitution into the differential equation, but I ended up getting another infinite series due to the Mclaurin series for $ln(x+1)$.

At any rate, I'm not sure they'll give us the answer, so I thought I'd post it here, I figured someone might be interested.